# Various ports in hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

I am trying to understand the various ports at which various daemons / processes listens at in a Hadoop cluster.

## core-site.xml

```
    <property>
            <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
            <value>hdfs://master.hadoop.cluster:54310</value>
    </property>
```

## yarn-site.xml

```
    <property>
            <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
            <value>master.hadoop.cluster:8032</value>
    </property>
```

I see we have three other ports, which are:

1) 50070  --> To see hdfs GUI
2) 8088   --> To see RM GUI
3) 8042   --> Not sure which GUI we can see at this port

As there are so many ports, I am not clear which port is meant for which thing. If I make HTTP request to port, say at 8032, it says this is `Hadoop IPC port`.

Can anyone help me understand this, what are the main port numbers which we should be aware of, and what processes listens at those ports.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The port defined in `fs.defaultFS` is for file system metadata operations. You cannot use it for accessing the Web UI.
**`8042`** is for NodeManager Web UI and **`8032`** is for ResourceManager IPC.

Refer

- [hdfs-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/hdfs-default.xml) - for HDFS related ports
- [yarn-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-common/yarn-default.xml) - for YARN related ports
- [mapred-default.xml](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/mapred-default.xml) - for JHS related ports.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, clarified the things.